# Self Hosted Speedtest Command Line Script

Tags: linux, network-speed

I would like to write my own local speedtest script with a server script for listening to connections. To try and not duplicate my efforts, I haven't found much while searching. I can find lots of over-the-internet tests (sppeedtest, ookla) but nothing that I can hosted myself and check upload/download from a local machine on my local network to see what the bandwidth is like.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Open Speed Test, that can be installed locally to test LAN speed.

http://openspeedtest.com/